# Disable iOS7 slide up menu in app

Tags: menu, ios7, cocos2d-x

in iOS7, there is a new menu to access when sliding up on the screen from bottom. Can I disable this while my cocos2d-x app is in focus?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. Control center is part of the OS, and Apple offers no API for it...